# Link specific to user django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a website where a list of users looking for a service is displayed to any one who signed up to provide the service. I have the following code:

```
      {% for customer in customers %}
                    <tr>

                        <td style = "text-align:center">{{ customer.user.first_name|title }} {{ customer.user.last_name|title }}</td>
                        <td style = "text-align:center">{{ customer.user.profile.address|title }}</td>
                        <td style = "text-align:center"><a href="{% url 'claim' %}">Claim</a></td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

For the claim link, how can I pass information about the specific user to the linked page(say claim.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add that info as a query parameter:

```
<td style = "text-align:center"><a href="{% url 'claim' user_id=customer.user.id%}">Claim</a></td>
```

Then, you can use this GET parameter in your view.

Your url should look something like this:

```
 url(r'^claim/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.ClaimView.as_view(), name='claim')
```

Then, in your view you can do this:

```
class ClaimView(View):
    def get(self, request, user_id, *args, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        # whatever you want to do
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks, Jahongir never knew you do something like that